# Data received from a microcontroller using npm serialport library on linux has some garbage bytes in addition to all the correct bytes

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, serial-port, uart

I have two similar setups with identical problem in both.

In first setup I have TI's MSP342 connected to a load cell and an encoder, sending 6 bytes of data to a RPi 3B (with raspbian) using serial port. It has direct connection to Tx and Rx pins between microcontroller and RPi.

In second setup I have MSP432 connected to pressure sensor and sending 3 bytes of sensor data to a computer running Ubuntu 18.04 using FTDI TTL to USB cable.

In both cases I use the npm serialport node.js library to receive the data and then bunch it into 6 byte or 3 byte chunks. This data is later plotted.

When I run the system, it works fine for 90% of the times. Sometimes, however, I see 1 or 2 spurious bytes on the receiving end which throws off my 3 or 6 byte groupings. The commands being sent to the microcontroller are always correct.

To make sure that microcontroller was not to blame, I connected the microcontroller Tx to another computer running windmill and compared the bytes received there. Windmill showed no spurious bytes. I have tried resetting the port which sometimes works.

```
// The node.js code on the RPi and computer side 

var dataArray = [];
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var port = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyUSB0", {
baudRate: 115200,
});

const ByteLength = SerialPort.parsers.ByteLength;
const parser = new ByteLength({length: 3});

var data = [0x21];
var counter = 0;

console.log("Starting test : " + data)
port.write(data);

port.pipe(parser);
parser.on('data', readdata);
//port.on('data', readdata);

function readdata(data) {
/*for (var i = 0; data[i] != null ; i++) {
    dataArray[i] = data[i];
}*/
counter =counter + 1;
dataArray1 = getHexString(data);
//console.log(data);
//console.log(dataArray);
console.log(counter+" "+dataArray1);
}

function getHexString(buffer) {
var newbuf = Buffer.from([buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2]])
var hexString = newbuf.toString('hex')
return hexString
}
```

Data sent form microcontroller
CA 83 AE
Data received on computer
00 CA 83 AE

Comment: Can you please also share the sketch for the microcontroller?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, for the raspberry pi version the microcontroller is connected directly i.e. GND, Rx and Tx of microcontroller to GND, Tx and Rx of Pi via jumper cables. Nothing inbetween. For the other version I use FTDI TTL to USB converter, but here again I connect the GND, Rx and Tx of microcontroller to corrosponding inputs of the converter. I am not using any pullup resistors etc.